# Getting redirect on Microsoft Office login after triggering Oauth 2.0 Authorization

Tags: azure, office365, azure-web-app-service, napa

I created a small Office-365 Web Add-in on the Napacloud with my MS Dev-Account which synchronizes files between OneDrive and our companies document repository. 
Once i press the synchronize button i send a REST request from Napa to my server which himself returns the login URL with the attached client ID and redirect URI (From an Azure Web-App which has been created on another MS Azure Account).
Now when i try to login to receive the Access Token i am getting constant redirects upon writing my email-Adress into the input field. Does it has something to do with domain specific Accounts ?

Comment: I'm not clear on the details here. You call your own REST endpoint to retrieve the Azure login URL? Then I guess you browse to that URL, enter your email address (but not password?) and you get redirected? Where?

Comment: i am using "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token......" but then when i type in the email adress i am getting a redirect from microsoft to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf" and then my whole GET parameters are gone. When i try to login now i am getting redirected again constantly.

Comment: What is the domain of the email address that you are typing in? And where are you being redirected to in the redirect loop?  Does the redirect loop happen before you enter your password on `/login.srf` or after?

Comment: It happens before. if i try log in with 'ABCdemo.onmicrosoft.com' i can login but once i try it with 'ABCsales.de' i am getting redirected

Comment: i tried a bit of tweaking when I directly approach my Servlet which deals with the authorization i am getting redirected to https://login.live.com before i can type password